# Orientation Problem in android

Tags: android, orientation

I am using two xml file on for landscape and another for portrait 
when i am trying to change my orientation landscape to portrait and portrait to landscape it shows the black screen
I want to remove that black screen what i have to do for this problem

Comment: i dont think u can do anythng for dis coz wen the orientation is changed the data is loaded fresly again so when the screen becomes black it indicates the data is loading again freshly into the changed orientation.

Comment: when landscape xml calling it take some time for excute so the black screen is displaying after sometimes the xml layout comes

Comment: @Rosalie is it possible to solve this using  thread

Comment: ya that happens coz of the downloading of data. whenever u change the orientation the data will be freshly loaded again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I understand now "that blank screen" is the delay in between while the activity is restarting.

How long does it take will strongly depend on what you're doing during onCreate(), since it is called every time the activity starts. You asked in the comments if threads will solve it: short answer, no, it's not that simple as spawning a new thread.

You may want to consider using [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) for the heavy objects in your activity. Take a look at this article for a excellent explanation: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html .

Alternatively, you can use static data in an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. See the Application as a Singleton post here: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218